# Why credit cards are sold through banks and not from Visa or MasterCard directly

Tags: credit-card

What is the reason that credit cards  are (usually) sold only through banks? Or are they always sold only through banks?

In any case, why cannot a company like Visa or MasterCard directly sell credit cards to the customers?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about an issue that the OP might be facing with respect to Personal Finance.

Comment: I think it is a good basic question. There are thousands of places you can get Visa/MasterCard but only one place for American Express/Discover yet they all advertise on TV.

Comment: I would argue that Knowing how all these mind-boggling financial stuff works does help in making decisions with regards to one's personal finance.

Comment: I won't open without community support, but I am in favor of this question, or something like it.  I am assuming it is common for people to assume Visa lends them money, but oh course they don't.  A good question might tease that out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Visa and Mastercard are not consumer-oriented companies. They do not consider individual consumers as their direct clients, and do not sell directly to them. Instead, their clients are financial institutions who participate in their networks (which is what they're selling). The institutions target the individual consumers (merchants and credit card holders).

American Express, for example, has a different business model. AX doesn't only sell network services to financial institutions, but also services to individual consumers. You can get a AX credit card/merchant account directly with AX, or through their client bank.